# How to resolve 'Cannot assign because string is incompatible with null or undefined' Flow error?

Tags: flowtype

I'm getting an error from flow, but I'm checking to verify that the error can never happen. How can I tell flow everything is OK?

```
/* @flow */

type A = {|
 test: string;
|}

type B = {|
 test: ?string;
|}

function foo(b: B): A {
  if (b && b.test) {
    return {
      test: b.test
    };
  }

  return { test: 'hi' };
}

const test: B = foo({ test: 'a' });
```

This is the error Flow is giving me.

```
21: const test: B = foo({ test: 'a' });
                    ^ Cannot assign `foo(...)` to `test` because string [1] is incompatible with null or undefined [2] in property `test`.
References:
4:  test: string;
          ^ [1]
8:  test: ?string;
          ^ [2]
```

But from the code I'm checking that test can't be null or undefined. So I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

[Live Example Here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN4A+qYGeAzhgFxiMBOAlgHYDmA3KkoBfdNnxgAQqQrVaDZmAD87bv0EjUUAK5cAxhg5wuYKHDgAKAEYsJAShbFyNMByhgrYAGSewlgHR0jLYUzmBgbHgYWmzGTmHxcows-oEYoWBCAmEiYc4RUTEUiQoA5AAWHCUZAhq6RozFNtKmFuSNYCUAhlVCtgKoQA)

Answer (score 3):

```
/* @flow */

type A = {|
 test: string;
|}

type B = {|
 test: ?string;
|}

declare var TestA: A;
declare var TestB: B;

TestB = TestA;
//      ^ Cannot assign `TestA` to `TestB` because string [1] is incompatible with null or undefined [2] in property `test`
```

It is because `{|test: string;}` is not subtype of `{|test: ?string;}`, we can mutate `TestB.test = null`, but it also mutate `TestA` where `test` should not be null.

`{|test: string;}` is subtype of `{| +test: ?string;}`. (`+` - read-only)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. This is the corrected code I believe.

```
/* @flow */

type A = {|
 test: string;
|}

type B = {|
 test: string;
|}

function foo(b: ?B): A {
  if (b && b.test) {
    return {
      test: b.test
    };
  }

  return { test: 'hi' };
}

const test: B = foo({ test: 'a' });
```

Comment: Not a syntax error, you made 'test' in type B a required property now. It shouldn;t be.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `?`. Are you trying to only make "B" have an optional property? With this it still won't be able to be  null but will allow undefined.